# Pandas Merge Dataframe, Keep duplicates consecutive

Tags: pandas, merge, duplicates

I'd like to merge dataframes df1 and df2, and preserve the row data in the order of original index value.

df3 is my desired output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat`:

```
pd.concat((df1,df2)).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thankyou! Worked nicely.

Comment: Does [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index) a stable sort?

Comment: Okay, seems `'mergesort'` does it. Sorry for bothering.